# accessing props inside react constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am unable to get props inside constructor that I have implemented using redux concept.

Code for container component

```
class UpdateItem extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props.item.itemTitle) // output: undefined
    this.state = {
        itemTitle: this.props.item.itemTitle,
        errors: {}
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e) {
    //If the input fields were directly within this
    //this component, we could use this.refs.[FIELD].value
    //Instead, we want to save the data for when the form is submitted
    let state = {};
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value.trim();
    this.setState(state);
}

    handleSubmit(e) {
    //we don't want the form to submit, so we pritem the default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    let errors = {};
    errors = this._validate();
    if(Object.keys(errors).length != 0) {
        this.setState({
            errors: errors
        });
        return;
    }
    let itemData = new FormData();
    itemData.append('itemTitle',this.state.itemTitle)

    this.props.onSubmit(itemData);
}

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getItemByID();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if (this.props.item.itemID != nextProps.item.itemID){
            //Necessary to populate form when existing item is loaded directly.
            this.props.getItemByID();
        }
    }


    render(){

        let {item} = this.props;
        return(
            <UpdateItemForm
            itemTitle={this.state.itemTitle}
            errors={this.state.errors}
            />
        );
    }
}

UpdateItem.propTypes = {
    item: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
    let item = {
        itemTitle: ''
    };


    return {
        item: state.itemReducer
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        getItemByID:()=>dispatch(loadItemByID(ownProps.params.id)),
        onSubmit: (values) => dispatch(updateItem(values))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(UpdateItem);
```

Inside render() method am able to get the props i.e. item from the redux but not inside constructor.

And code for the actions to see if the redux implementation correct or not,

```
    export function loadItemByID(ID){
        return function(dispatch){
            return itemAPI.getItemByID(ID).then(item => {
                dispatch(loadItemByIDSuccess(item));
            }).catch(error => {
                throw(error);
            });
        };
    }

export function loadItemByIDSuccess(item){
    return {type: types.LOAD_ITEM_BY_ID_SUCCESS, item}
}
```

Finally my reducer looks as follows,

```
export default function itemReducer(state = initialState.item, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.LOAD_ITEM_BY_ID_SUCCESS:
            return Object.assign([], state = action.item, {
                item: action.item
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I have googled to get answers with no luck, I don't know where i made a mistake. If some one point out for me it would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you can't access the props in the constructor is that it is only called once, before the component is first mounted.

The action to load the item is called in the `componentWillMount` function, which occurs after the constructor is called.

It appears like you are trying to set a default value in the `mapStateToProps` function but aren't using it at all

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
    // this is never used
    let item = {
        itemTitle: ''
    };


    return {
        item: state.itemReducer
    };
}
```

The next part I notice is that your are taking the state from redux and trying to inject it into the component's local state

```
this.state = {
    itemTitle: this.props.item.itemTitle,
    errors: {}
};
```

Mixing redux state and component state is very rarely a good idea and should try to be avoided.  It can lead to inconsistency and and hard to find bugs.

In this case, I don't see any reason you can't replace all the uses of `this.state.itemTitle` with `this.props.items.itemTitle` and remove it completely from the component state.

---

#### Observations

There are some peculiar things about your code that make it very difficult for me to infer the intention behind the code.

Firstly the reducer

```
export default function itemReducer(state = initialState.item, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.LOAD_ITEM_BY_ID_SUCCESS:
            return Object.assign([], state = action.item, {
                item: action.item
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

You haven't shown the `initialState` object, but generally it represents the whole initial state for the reducer, so using `initialState.item` stands out to me.  You may be reusing a shared initial state object for all of the reducers so I'm not too concerned about this.

What is very confusing the `Object.assign` call. I'm not sure it the intention is to output an object replacing `item` in the state, or if it is to append `action.item` to an array, or to have an array with a single item as the resulting state.  The `state = action.item` part is also particularly puzzling as to it's intention in the operation.

This is further confused by the `PropTypes` for `UpdateItem` which requires `item` to be an array

```
UpdateItem.propTypes = {
    item: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
```

But the usage in the component treats it like and object

```
this.state = {
  // expected some kind of array lookup here |
  //                          V---------------
    itemTitle: this.props.item.itemTitle,
    errors: {}
};
```

---

#### Update from comments

[Here is a example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybaZvj) of what I was talking about in the comments.  It's a simplified version of your code (I don't have all your components.  I've also modified a few things to match my personal style, but hopefully you can still see what's going on.

Comment: My initial state object looks like this, `item: []` . And the reason i use `itemTitle: this.props.item.itemTitle` is to edit the state passed to `<UpdateItemForm >` component allowing a user to edit what they have posted inside input tag. when i pass the props to the `<UpdateItemForm>` componet it becomes controlled component i.e not allowing to edit the form. To save characters i have this `<input type="text" name="itemTitle" value={itemTitle} onChange={handleChange}/>` inside `<UpdateItemForm>` component. My intention in the reducer is to return array.

Comment: I have tried by adding parent component and moving `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` from `UpdateItem` to the parent component so that item props passed down to `< UpdateItem item={item}>` and tried to see the props inside constructor but there is no value displayed using `console.log(this.props.item)`

Comment: Try putting `console.log(state)` as the first line of `mapStateToProps`.  I think that will help you understand what is going wrong.

Comment: `console.log("state "+ JSON.stringify(state))` first shows previously loaded items. My backend server just returns one item by id i.e. `db.Where("id = ?", itemID).First(&item)` but am seeing previously loaded items at the browser console. Lastly it becomes empty `"itemReducer":[]` and i think the problem is related to my reducer setting but don't know how to correct it.

Comment: Assuming you want to append the new item to the existing array, you can use [`state.concat(action.item)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=control) to immutably create a new array.  As the items appear to have an id, I'd be tempted to use that as the key and store them in an object for quick lookups.  If I have time later I'll knock together a jsfiddle of what I mean.

Comment: I have made small change i.e **handling null props** ... `if(!this.props.item){return (<div>loading ... </div>)} return (< UpdateItem item={item}>)` @Michael Peyper