# Get default state value by receiving prop data - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm new to `react.js`.
I'd like to get default value of state `following_status` by receiving `props.user.following_status`.

I'm passing user object ( `user = { following_status: 'following', id:123 }` ) to `ReactionButton` component. `ReactionButton` component is looks like this:

```
class RelationButton extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(props.user.following_status) #  undefined!!!

    this.state = {
      following_status: props.user.following_status
    }
...
    render() {
       if (this.state.following_status == 'following') {
         <UnFollowBtn/>
       } else {
         <FollowBtn/>
       }
    }
```

`RelationButton` was called by  `UserCardHeader` component.

```
const UserCardHeader = (props) => {
  const user = props.user;
  return(
    <header className="user-card--full__header">
      <RelationButton user={user}></RelationButton>
    </header>
  )
}
```

I don't understand why `console.log(props.user.following_status)` returns `undefined`. I googled many websites like those:

- [React component initialize state from props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063468/react-component-initialize-state-from-props)
- [accessing props inside react constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559509/accessing-props-inside-react-constructor)

those answers suggest

```
class FirstComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          x: props.initialX
        };
    }
}
```

but this didn't work for me.

If I add `componentWillReceiveProps` to the codes above,

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    console.log(props.user.following_status)   #=> "following"
    this.setState({following_status: props.user.following_status})
  }
```

everything works well. However I think it's weird solution and sometimes doesn't work. Why can't I receive object props in `constructor(props) {}` section?

Comment: you have to show who is rendering `RelationButton`

Comment: @MilosMosovsky thanks I added to the question

Comment: can you try to `console.log('render')` inside `RelationButton` render method and see if it's not called twice? Maybe you did weird wrapping or user is asynchronous and therefore it's not available in mount but `componentWillReceiveProps` will get called on every props update

Comment: show how do you use `UserCardHeader `

Comment: @MilosMosovsky the out put is `render render` yes actually called twice

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk there is more than 4 parent components  - I couldn't display all of them

Comment: if you log `props.user` in your `UserCardHeader` do you get any instances of `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the full code, we can't tell what's wrong but it is obvious that `following_status` comes asynchronously to the component and that's why is not accessible right away in the constructor.

To somehow fix it you can detect if props have changed and reset state accordingly in `componentDidUpdate`.

```
class RelationButton extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(props.user.following_status) #  undefined!!!

    this.state = {
      following_status: props.user.following_status
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.user.following_status !== this.props.user.following_status) {
      this.setState({ following_status: this.props.user.following_status })
    }
  }

  render() {
     // you forgot about return statements :
     if (this.state.following_status == 'following') {
       return <UnFollowBtn/>
     } else {
       return <FollowBtn/>
     }
  }
}
```